# cookie unset not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am using remember option in my login page.I think I am doing right but when in logout I just amn't able to unset the cookie variable.I am using CI but for cookie I am using native cookie.What am I doint wrong?My code:
in login controller:

```
function index(){
if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])){
  redirect('index');
}elseif($this->input->post()){
  $username = $this->input->post('username');
  $password = $this->input->post('password');
  $remember = $this->input->post('remember');
  if($remember){
      $time = time()+60*60*24*365;
      setcookie('remember_me', $username , $time);
  }
  $this->session->set_userdata('user_name', $user_name);
  $this->session->set_userdata('full_name', $full_name);
  $this->session->set_userdata('server', $server->exchange_server);
  redirect('index');
}else{
  $this->load->view('login');
}
}
function logout(){
 $this->session->unset_userdata('user_name');
 $this->session->unset_userdata('full_name');
 $this->session->unset_userdata('server');
 $data['login'] = 'Logout Successfully.';
 $data['class'] = 'success';
 $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
/* To unset cookie i tried following different approach but to no avail*/
setcookie('remember_me');
setcookie('remember_me', '', $time()-60*60*24*365);
setcookie('remember_me', false);
unset($_COOKIE['remember_me']);
 redirect('login');
}
```

but to no avail. I just can't unset cookie and when user who has checked remember me option trys to logout it's not happening.
Any help/suggestion is welcome.Thanks

I don't know what is the problem but I used jquery plugin for cookie delete {https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie}. I included jquery.cookie.js and then on logout click I deleted the cookie set as $.removeCookie('remember_me')

Comment: Whene do you call `logout()` function ? In this function `$time()-60*60*24*365` seems to be `0`

Comment: @alesdario didn't quite catch you.What do you mean?I call logout() function when user wants to logout through logut button.

Comment: `setcookie('remember_me', '', $time()-60*60*24*365);` should be `setcookie('remember_me', '', time()-60*60*24*365);` or `setcookie('remember_me', '', $time-60*60*24*365);`

Comment: @alesdario not working :(

Comment: Why are you using native setcookie function and not the CI instead?

Comment: @alesdario i also tried using ci cookie but still i can set cookie but not unset or delete it on logout. For the set cookie I used 
$this->input->set_cookie('remember_me', $username, 7200);
to get cookie value i used
$this->input->cookie('remember_me');
to delete or unset cookie on logout i used
delete_cookie('remember_me')
but to no avail. I just can't unset or delete cookie.

Comment: I've improved my respose below. Read it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the problem but I used jquery plugin for cookie delete {https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie}. I included jquery.cookie.js and then on logout click I deleted the cookie set as $.removeCookie('remember_me') and it's working fine.Thanks for the suggestions and help.

Comment: it seems there is some bug in library (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). I was not able to remove cookie using any other way but this way. many thanks to samjhana joshi

Answer (score 11):

with

```
unset($_COOKIE['some_cookie'])
```

you don't delete the Cookie on the browser,  you unset the variabile `$_COOKIE['some_cookie']`.

If you want delete the browser cookie you have to set the expiration date in the past:

```
setcookie("some_cookie", "", time()-3600);
```

---

If it doesn't work try setting properly the cookie domain.

Create:

```
setcookie('some_cookie', null, time() + 3600, "/");
```

Delete:

```
setcookie('some_cookie', null, time() - 3600, "/");
```

Comment: tried using the option you have mentioned but to no avail so i just deleted the cookie using javascript as mentioned in answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use this function please

```
delete_cookie()
```

And for native php cookie use

```
 unset($_COOKIE['remember_me']);
```

Or use CI function as follows

```
setcookie('remember_me', null, -1);
```

That's all

Comment: @SamyMassout as it's CI function i tried using it also as follows but to no avail.
$this->load->helper('cookie');
delete_cookie('remember_me');
but it's not working cookie isn't unsetting.

Comment: both isn't working either. Why?? Is it due to setting cookie to time of next year or what?

Comment: where you set remember me ? could you post this part of code ?

Comment: I  set remember me in login > index function as 
if($remember){
      $time = time()+60*60*24*365;
      setcookie('remember_me', $username , $time);
  }

Comment: @SamyMassoud what is a CI Function?